# Change $HOME for program generated files

Tags: environment-variables

I despise all junk that programs generate in my home directory; I'd like to see this stuff placed in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`.

However, there are too many programs to configure and most of them probably have path hardcoded to `$HOME` anyway.

I'd like to know if it's possible to somehow change `$HOME` to `~/.home` **while** keeping original home dir for such things as BASH and that minimal file browser that apps use for opening/saving files.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across [libetc](http://ordiluc.net/fs/libetc/) a couple months ago. I've never used it, and it is an `LD_PRELOAD` hack, so I'd be careful, but it sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to backup important dot-files in my $HOME and see how it works. Here's a guide on ArchWiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libetc